# How to extract the output to CSV using terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have created multiple instances using terraform I need to export that output to CSV

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what information you want to export, but, the information for all resources created by terraform saved/stored under the tfstate file.

You can open the file and check it/extract directly.

You can run the following command to list all resources that were created

```
terraform state list
```

And you can run the following command to get the details of a resrouce.

```
terraform state show <resource name from list>
```